# Matrix generation from a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a column vector `A`. When `A` is a scalar I can use the colon operator to generate a vector like so

```
B = A-m:n:A+p
```

However, what I want to do is different. I want the result B to look like so,

```
[A-m, A-m+1 ... A ... , A+n-1, A+n]
```

I know I can accomplish this by using `repmat` on `-m:n:p` followed with a `bsxfun` added with the original `A` matrix.

Is there a more direct method?

Comment: So you want `bsxfun(@plus,A,[-m:1:n])`? I'm getting confused by your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy a handful instances of **column vector** v, you can always use

```
B = [v, v, v, ... v];
```

Or for **row vector**

```
B = [v ; v ; v ; ... v];
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy vectorized way is this:

```
NewMatrix = diag(A)*ones(length(A),m+n+1) + ones(length(A),m+n+1)*diag(-m:1:n)
```

Answer (score 0):

not a one-liner...

```
>> a=[1;2];
>> r=3:2:10;
>> repmat(a,1,size(r,2))+repmat(r,size(a,1),1)

ans =

     4     6     8    10
     5     7     9    11
```